# Why does spontaneous atomic decay usually go into a quantum state which has the opposite parity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

An answer to the question [Probability of an hydrogen electron staying in a certain orbital](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411002/probability-of-an-hydrogen-electron-staying-in-a-certain-orbital) says

> When an atom spontaneously decays it typically decays into a quantum state which has the opposite parity.

but does not give any reason/explanation.

Is there any theoretical explanation in quantum or classical mechanics for the fact that atom spontaneous decay typically does into a state with opposite parity (the electron of course will move to a lower energy level as per quantum mechanics with opposite parity)?

---

Some other relevant resources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission

Comment: The way this question was worded previously was difficult to understand. Part of the reason for that difficulty was that the links were given without explicitly stating the relevant content of those links. I have attempted to improve the post by putting the most important information at the beginning and moving the bare links to the end.

Comment: But anyway here's a hint: what term in the Hamiltonian leads to spontaneous decay? Can you write down the interaction term between the electron and the electromagnetic field surrounding the atom?

Comment: Doesn't this just trivially come from dipole selection rules? To get a non zero amplitude for states to couple to a long wavelength wave in the dipole approx